# Docker compose env variable not substituted

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I have my docker-compose setup like this

`docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3.9'
services:
  busybox:
    image: busybox:latest
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=${DB_HOST}
    env_file:
      - test.properties
```

`test.properties`:

```bash
DB_URL=jdbc://mysql://${DB_HOST}:app_db
```

`.env`:

```bash
DB_HOST=localhost
```

when I run [`docker-compose config` command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_config/), the output is like this,

```yaml
services:
  busybox:
    environment:
      DB_HOST: localhost
      DB_URL: jdbc://mysql://:app_db
    image: busybox:latest
version: '3.9'
```

As you see, the environment variable DB_HOST is defined as 'localhost' in the .env file but the variable is set to '' by docker-compose in the environment variable 'DB_HOST' and is showing as `jdbc://mysql://:app_db`. But I want the value of DB_HOST like this `DB_HOST: jdbc://mysql://localhost:app_db`. How could I achieve this?

My docker and docker-compose version looks like this

```
> docker -v
Docker version 20.10.5, build 55c4c88

> docker-compose version
docker-compose version 1.28.5, build c4eb3a1f
docker-py version: 4.4.4
CPython version: 3.9.0
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1h  22 Sep 2020
```

The workaround as suggested by [antonio-petricca](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67917196/docker-compose-env-variable-not-substituted/67917494#67917494) is working, but I want to know if anybody happens to solve the issue without setting the env variable before running docker-compose up? This used to work earlier with the older versions of docker-compose, but with some updates, it stopped working. I am not sure it's broken on which docker-compose version.

Comment: @BMitch The question that you marked as duplicate is a bit different than my case. In that case the variable defined in env_file is not available within compose. So the suggestion was to define the variable in .env file. In my case, I have the variable in .env file and I want to use it in env_file. Even if docker compose doesn't resolve the variable in the test.properties file, and keep it like this, DB_URL=jdbc://mysql://${DB_HOST}:app_db, my code will work. But the problem is docker-compose change this to DB_URL=jdbc://mysql://:app_db, which makes my app not working

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue some time ago, and workaround was:

```
#!/bin/bash

DB_HOST=localhost

DB_HOST=${DB_HOST} docker-compose # ... command arguments ...
```

You can repeat the same for other variables.

Tell me if that works for you.

Regards.

Comment: Yup, that is the workaround I am using too right now. But in my case, I also have an environment variable like this `spring.jpa.show-sql`, env variables with dot(.) and they can't be set on the command line. Will update my question with these details

Comment: Did you happen to solve this issue for you? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe another workaround is to add DB_HOST to your test.properties file?

```
DB_HOST=${DB_HOST:-localhost}
DB_URL=jdbc://mysql://${DB_HOST}:app_db
```

However, you still have to keep .env for

```
environment:
  - DB_HOST=${DB_HOST}
```

So you have to make sure the values are the same at both settings...not sure if it is a better solution.